# Regular expression to capture each letter to the same capture group

Tags: regex, powershell

My string to be parsed consist of letters separated by spaces. Letters can only occur zero or one time. An example is `" A B C D E"` or `"C E D"`. I need a pattern that captures appearances of all letters into the same capture group so that I can iterate over that group later.

```
" A B C D E " -match "<regex>"
```

I expect the result to be:

```
Group 'Letter' match #1: A
Group 'Letter' match #2: B
Group 'Letter' match #3: C
Group 'Letter' match #4: D
Group 'Letter' match #5: E
```

Comment: That sounds a bit simplistic to me. Any attempts yet?

Comment: I do not know how to construct a repeated capture group - all with optional occurrences.

Comment: But is a capture group necessary? You could perhaps match all the letters, put then in a list/array and you use an index (or a loop or similar) to get each one.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot capture the entire block into a group and then loop over the results? Any hint as to what language you are using?

Comment: yeah, that is another approach, I just wanted to keep my architecture where the result matches drive further processing, more so if regex is absolutely capable of creating that array to me - with a repeated capture group

Comment: @PeterAronZentai So `A B - C D` should result into...?

Comment: this should result a 4 item group with A) B) C) D) respectively

Comment: A simple 'matchall' (depends on the regex implementation) should do... [like this?](http://regex101.com/r/eY6rG6)

Comment: @PeterAronZentai I think you're overcomplicating things. The regex [Jerry](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1578604/jerry) just showed should do the job then

Comment: jeah, @Jerry 's approach could work - I need to test.

Comment: Darn, g is not supported by my platform (PowerShell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Powershell, the following gives you an array of all regex matches:

```
$regex = [regex] '\b\p{L}\b'
$allmatches = $regex.Matches(" A B C D E FG");
```

You can then access the matches using `$allmatches.Item[]` (which will contain `"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"` but not `"F"` or `"G"`).

Comment: Is `\p{L}` a shorthand somehow for `\p{Lu}` ? Or, more likely, since the enumeration value `Lu` is 0, then the `L` is unrecognized and treated as a zero? (Reference: [UnicodeCategory Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.unicodecategory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

Comment: @MichaelSorens: `\p{L}` stands for the Unicode property "letter"; `\p{Lu}` is the uppercase letter subset of that property, and `\p{Ll}` is the lowercase subset. There are a few others, see http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Comment: The problem is that the given patter will match  "ABCDE" as well

Comment: @PeterAronZentai: I may have misunderstood then. Your question said that letters can occur zero or one time, so I assumed you didn't need to test for longer "words". If you want the regex to only find letters that are single, then you can use [word boundary anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). Editing...